# postfix, чтение информации из ldap

Tags: postfix, email, ldap, linux

Для оформления ограничений в Postfix, хочу использовать как карту, уже существующую группу в ldap. Вот ее содержимое

```
dn: cn=mailFullAccess,ou=mail,ou=Groups,dc=my,dc=myorggidNumber: 5555memberUid: user1memberUid: user2memberUid: user3memberUid: user4memberUid: user5description: for unlimited access to mailobjectClass: topobjectClass: posixGroupcn: mailFullAccess
```

результат ldapseach запроса (запрос существующего пользователя)

```
[root@mail ~]# ldapsearch -LLL -x -h ldap.host -b 'cn=mailFullAccess,ou=mail,ou=Groups,dc=my,dc=myorg' memberuid=user1dn: cn=mailFullAccess,ou=mail,ou=Groups,dc=my,dc=myorggidNumber: 5555memberUid: user1memberUid: user2memberUid: user3memberUid: user4memberUid: user5description: for unlimited access to mailobjectClass: topobjectClass: posixGroupcn: mailFullAccess
```

результат ldapseach запроса (запрос НЕсуществующего пользователя)

```
[root@mail ~]# ldapsearch -LLL -x -h ldap.host -b 'cn=mailFullAccess,ou=mail,ou=Groups,dc=my,dc=myorg' memberuid=user1234
```

-ВЫВОДА НЕТ-

Запрос к группе в в виде файла для Postfix - ldap_full.cf

```
search_base = cn=mailFullAccess,ou=mail,ou=Groups,dc=my,dc=myorgserver_host = ldap.hostquery_filter = (memberUid=%u)result_attribute = memberUidscope = onebind = yesbinddn = cn=poweruser,ou=Service,dc=my,dc=myorgbindpw = latropassworddebuglevel = 0
```

Пытаюсь проверить

```
postmap -q "user1@domain.ru" ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap/full_ldap.cf
```

пусто, пробую несуществующую абрукадабру

```
postmap -q "user123456" ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap/full_ldap.cf
```

также пусто.. что не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

search_base на уровень вверх, фильтр немного поправить и все работает!

```
search_base = ou=mail,ou=Groups,dc=my,dc=myorgserver_host = ldap.hostquery_filter = (&(cn=mailFullAccess)(memberUid=%u))result_attribute = memberUidscope = subbind = yes
```

и в зависимости от того, что вам надо возвращать в качестве значения ключа то добавим (для OK)

```
result_format = %s OK
```